# How to concatenate RNA-seq files generated in differnt lanes

Tags: linux, bioinformatics

I have very large RNA-seq files generated in different lanes. I extracted few of the file names as shown below.

```
MC9_FNEN_638A_S19_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz
MC9_FNEN_638A_S19_L008_R2_001.fastq.gz
MC9_FNEN_638A_S9_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
MC9_FNEN_638A_S9_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
MC9_FNEN_638A_S9_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
MC9_FREN_638A_S9_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
MC9_FREN_638A_S9_L006_R1_001.fastq.gz
MC9_FREN_638A_S9_L006_R2_001.fastq.gz
MC9_FREN_638A_S9_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz
MC9_FREN_638A_S9_L008_R2_001.fastq.gz
MC9_ZH_637A_S74_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
MC9_ZH_637A_S74_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
MC9_ZH_637A_S74_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz
MC9_ZH_637A_S74_L003_R2_001.fastq.gz
MC9_ZH_637A_S74_L007_R1_001.fastq.gz
MC9_ZH_637A_S74_L007_R2_001.fastq.gz
MC9_ZH_637A_S74_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz
MC9_ZH_637A_S74_L008_R2_001.fastq.gz
MC9_ZH_637A_S84_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz
MC9_ZH_637A_S84_L008_R2_001.fastq.gz
DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L006_R1_001.fastq.gz
DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L006_R2_001.fastq.gz
DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L007_R1_001.fastq.gz
DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L007_R2_001.fastq.gz
DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz
DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L008_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

I want to concatenate all the sequence generated in different lanes for the forward and reverse read.  For example the first 10 lines are sequence file from the same animal and specific tissue (`MC9_FREN`). I want to concatenate all the forward read  `XXXXX_R1_001.fastq.gz` that are generated in different lanes and put in the file name `MC9_FREN_R1.fastq.gz` and all reverse reads `XXXX_R2_001.fastq.gz` to `MC9_FREN_R2.fastq.gz`

```
cat MC9_FREN_638A_S19_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz MC9_FREN_638A_S9_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz  MC9_FREN_638A_S9_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz  MC9_FREN_638A_S9_L007_R1_001.fastq.gz MC9_FREN_638A_S9_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz > MC9_FREN_R1.fastq.gz
cat MC9_FREN_638A_S19_L008_R2_001.fastq.gz MC9_FREN_638A_S9_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz MC9_FREN_638A_S9_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz  MC9_FREN_638A_S9_L007_R2_001.fastq.gz MC9_FREN_638A_S9_L008_R2_001.fastq.gz  > MC9_FREN_R2.fastq.gz
cat MC9_ZH_637A_S74_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz MC9_ZH_637A_S74_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz  MC9_ZH_637A_S74_L007_R1_001.fastq.gz MC9_ZH_637A_S74_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz  MC9_ZH_637A_S84_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz > MC9_ZH_R1.gz
cat MC9_ZH_637A_S74_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz  MC9_ZH_637A_S74_L003_R2_001.fastq.gz MC9_ZH_637A_S74_L007_R2_001.fastq.gz MC9_ZH_637A_S74_L008_R2_001.fastq.gz MC9_ZH_637A_S84_L008_R2_001.fastq.gz > MC9_ZH_R2.gz
cat DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L006_R1_001.fastq.gz DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L007_R1_001.fastq.gz DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz  > DR14_DCRP_R1.gz   
cat DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz  DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L006_R2_001.fastq.gz DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L007_R2_001.fastq.gz DR14_DCRP_479C_S50_L008_R2_001.fastq.gz  > DR14_DCRP_R1.gz
```

Comment: Yes? What is the question. You have now concatenated the files. Is that the type of "merging" that you want to do?

Comment: I have very large number of files, writing each file name manually may be time consuming. I wonder if you could write a command line using regular expression.

Comment: What is the logic behind what files should be concatenated?

Comment: For example the first 10 lines are sequence file from the same animal and specific tissue (MC9_PREN). I want to merge all XXXXX_R1_001.fastq.gz and put in the file name MC9_PREN_R1.fastq.gz and all XXXX_R2_001.fastq.gz to MC9_PREN_R2.fastq.gz

Comment: I don't think you are using the word "merge" in the way that we, as computing people, would expect. Please update your question to provide a short _worked example_ of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: There is 0 effort and previous work. This is not a question, you are asking for someone to do your work for free. Flagged

Comment: Re your example. Please stop thinking in terms of animal tissues and rephrase the question in a way that can be solved without your domain knowledge. How did you select a group of files for concatenating? How did you decide the order of these files? How did you derive the target filename?

Comment: Uh, so you want `zcat MC9_PREN_638A_S19_L*R1_001.fastq.gz > MC9_PREN_R1.fastq.gz`?

Comment: @muru No, that would decompress the data. There is no need to decompress it.

Comment: @Kusalananda can gzip files be simply cat'd to make another valid gzip file? If so, `cat MC9_PREN_638A_S19_L*R1_001.fastq.gz > MC9_PREN_R1.fastq.gz`, otherwise `zcat MC9_PREN_638A_S19_L*R1_001.fastq.gz | gzip > MC9_PREN_R1.fastq.gz`

Comment: @muru Yes, this works for `gzip`, `bzip2`, `xz` and a few others (concat file is still valid compressed file). The issue here is to automatically detecting the `MC9_PREN` (etc.) prefixes from the set of existing files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following loop gives us the unique filename prefixes of the FastQ files in the current directory.  It relies on the fact that there will always be four underscores (`_`) between the filename prefix that we want and the `R1` or `R2` later in the filename.

```
for name in *.fastq.gz; do
    printf '%s\n' "${name%_*_*_*_R[12]*}"
done | uniq
```

The following is equivalent, but does not use a loop (rather than deleting the last bit of the filename, this keeps the first bit of the filename):

```
printf '%s\n' *.fastq.gz | sed 's/^\([^_]*_[^_]*\).*/\1/' | uniq
```

With the given list of files, either of the above returns

```
DR14_DCRP
MC9_FNEN
MC9_FREN
MC9_ZH
```

We then read these prefixes and create our concatenated files:

```
for name in *.fastq.gz; do
    printf '%s\n' "${name%_*_*_*_R[12]*}"
done | uniq |
while read prefix; do
    cat "$prefix"*R1*.fastq.gz >"${prefix}_R1.fastq.gz"
    cat "$prefix"*R2*.fastq.gz >"${prefix}_R2.fastq.gz"
done
```

or, using the `sed` code from above,

```
printf '%s\n' *.fastq.gz | sed 's/^\([^_]*_[^_]*\).*/\1/' | uniq |
while read prefix; do
    cat "$prefix"*R1*.fastq.gz >"${prefix}_R1.fastq.gz"
    cat "$prefix"*R2*.fastq.gz >"${prefix}_R2.fastq.gz"
done
```

No code above uses `bash`-specific (or GNU-specific) features and should work in all POSIX shells.

---

UPDATE: I work with bioinformaticians, and a colleague of mine commented:

> One should not just simply merge fastq files... In an ideal world, one should map each lane separately, adding an appropriate RG, and then merge the BAM files. Because lane-specific effects exist, etc. It can be more or less important, depending on the downstream application of course.

For questions about this, please refer to [the Bioinformatics Stack Exchange site](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

**`Bash`** solution:

```
for f in *.fastq.gz; do 
    [[ "$f" =~ ^([^_]+_[^_]+)_.*(_[^_]+)_[0-9]+\.fastq\.gz$ ]]
    cat "$f" >> "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.fastq.gz"
done
```

---

- `^([^_]+_[^_]+)_.*(_[^_]+)_[0-9]+\.fastq\.gz$` - the crucial regex pattern to capture the first 2 prefixes into the 1st captured group (for ex. `MC9_PREN`) and `R`-named suffix into the 2nd captured group (for ex. `_R1`)